# RadioButtonList SelectedIndexChanged generic event not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Developed a slightly dynamic page that builds a Question and Answer page based on information from a database.  Everything works great except i cant get the RadioButtonList event to trigger with a minor MsgBox response to validate object sender and selected ListItem information.

#### Page_Load

```
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        With Globals.tst

            .GetBrandInformation(Page.RouteData.Values("brand"),
              Page.RouteData.Values("year"),
              Page.RouteData.Values("month"))

            'Load up Question DataSet
            For Each quest As Question In .Questions

                Dim tr As New HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow
                Dim td As New HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell
                td.Attributes.Add("class", "tdQ")       'Add class attribute to <td> element, creating 'class="tdQ"'
                Dim lbl As New Label
                lbl.ID = "lbl" & quest.ID
                lbl.Text = quest.Text

                td.Controls.Add(lbl)
                tr.Cells.Add(td)
                tblContent.Rows.Add(tr)

                tr = New HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow
                td = New HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell
                td.Attributes.Add("class", "tdA")       'Add class attribute to <td> element, creating 'class="tdA"'

                Dim rbl As New RadioButtonList
                rbl.ID = "rblT" & .ID & "_Q" & quest.ID
                AddHandler rbl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf rbl_SelectedIndexChanged     'Attach generic event handler to control

                Dim li As New ListItem

                'Load up Answer Dataset
                For Each answ As Answer In quest.Answers
                    li.Text = answ.Value
                    li.Value = "T" & .ID & "-Q" & quest.ID & "-A" & answ.ID & "-C" & answ.Correct

                    'Add built ListItem to RadioButtonList
                    rbl.Items.Add(li)
                    li = New ListItem
                Next

                td.Controls.Add(rbl)
                tr.Cells.Add(td)
                tblContent.Rows.Add(tr)
            Next

        End With
        '
    End If
```

Below is the Generic Event Handler Logic i am trying to attach to the RadioButtonList(s).

```
Protected Sub rbl_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox(CType(sender, RadioButtonList).ID & " Clicked.")
    MsgBox("Radio Button Selected: " & CType(sender, RadioButtonList).ID & " is Correct? " & CType(sender, RadioButtonList).SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Anyone see anything wrong with the design, or know why the Event is not being triggered?

#### Edited 2012-11-20

Ok changed the `rbl` object to do `AutoPostBack = true` but that made life even more unbearable ;)  Then quickly reverted back as the Q&A list i have is randomly generated on the Questions and Answers so the end-user would be given a new random order of questions upon every click of the ListItem.

Although i am getting some response back from the call backs still not getting the JavaScript response i am expecting by using either a defined JavaScript file or inline `Response.Write`/`ClientScript.Register`.

Created a debugging method into the Content Page:

```
Public Shared Sub Show(msg As String, Optional pg As Page = Nothing)
    Dim cmsg As String = msg.Replace("'", "\'")
    Dim scr As String = "<script type=""text/javascript"">alert('" & cmsg & "');</script>"

    If pg Is Nothing Then
        pg = CType(HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler, Page)
    End If

    If (pg IsNot Nothing) And Not (pg.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("alert")) Then
        pg.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Alert), "alert", scr)
    End If
End Sub
```

On page Load this method fires and as expected, but when placed inside the SelectedIndexChanged event it never fires off.

Still perplexed on why it works on general execution but not triggered execution.

Userful Method for those that like to create .Net methods that implement Javascript. [.Net Slave - Javascript Alert.Show Class](http://madskristensen.net/post/JavaScript-AlertShow(e2809dmessagee2809d)-from-ASPNET-code-behind.aspx)

Comment: Ok think i got it fixed....gonna verify in a minute without the Alert interruption of the Postback.  Anyone know if there is a Modal form of the Javascript Alert window so it doesnt freeze the PostBack behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take it OUT of the `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then`

this is because when you DO postback, the...

```
    AddHandler rbl.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf rbl_SelectedIndexChanged
```

...needs to be rebound before it can fire.

So basically, remove the `If Not Page.IsPostBack Then` and `End If`.

Oh, and get rid of the `MsgBox()` code too - this will kill the page from doing anything. If you want to output an `Alert()` then do something like:

```
    Dim script As String = String.Format("alert('{0}');", ""Radio Button Selected: " & CType(sender, RadioButtonList).ID & " is Correct? " & CType(sender, RadioButtonList).SelectedValue")
    page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(page.[GetType](), "alert", script, True)
```

**UPDATE:**

you also want to set `AutoPostback = true;` on your RBL. This tells the page to postback as soon as it's changed. the handler only fires if `AutoPostBack` is true.

Comment: would having a MasterPage/ContentPage effect this?  Placed the logic that builds the body of the ContentPage outside of the PostBack logic and still not getting the MsgBox expected behaviour.  Wondering if there is a setting i am missing.

Comment: Nope, shouldn't affect it. If you're totally not sure, then put the code to build the list in the page's preInit instead - before anything else gets done. Just added some more to my answer too - `MsgBox` will likely kill your script - it will just hang; don't use it.

Comment: Ultimately the MsgBox/Alert is only for debugging purposes.  At production, it will be used to keep track of information as it is selected.  Ill implement the Alert methodology.  Was hoping to stay away from client side scripting but guess i cant get away from it.

Comment: So if its for debugging then just do `Response.Write("<script>alert('" + YourLongMessage + "');</script>")` for quick and dirty

Comment: The trouble with MsgBox is you're asking the server to show the message - and they don't really like doing it, they prefer to crash :)

Comment: yeah Crash first and help the developer last.  Usual MS implementation ;)

Comment: Ok, not getting any JS response when i select a ListItem, at least in the SelectedIndexChanged event on either a Generic Event Handler or a Well-Defined Event Handler.  I added another RBL to do some validation in conjunction with the dynamic.  Neither is triggering the Alert script, irregardless of me using Page.ClientScript or Response.Write inside the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: Edited my original post, for further debugging.  Maybe i am misplacing or not making a proper setting for `RBL` but it works in general page level execution in the Content Page, but neither the Dynamic/Static RBL `SelectIndexChanged` events trigger this same method execution.

Comment: Yeah renested the Control creation outside of the `IsPostback` check and it kicks off the Alert now.  Going to put some more debuging controls into the Content Page so i dont necessarily have the interruption that the JS Alert method causes.

Comment: Excellent :) Glad its all working now. I would appreciate it if you mark this as answered - if this was the answer of course.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19833/discussion-between-goldbishop-and-darren)